# Logging Information from Gurobi Java Interface

Tags: java, logging, gurobi

Is there a way get detailed logging information about an optimization problem solved using Gurobi's Java interface. Maybe something like a method that prints logging information. `GRBEnv` can be initialized with a log file, but the information there does not allow you to look at matrices, variables and constraints. Programmatically generating those is cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GRBModel.write()` is the method to look at. Special attention should be paid to the file extensions.:
http://www.gurobi.com/doc/46/refman/node275.html